# My optical keyboard SK61 sometimes doesn't even see my click

Tags: keyboard, switch, typing

Sometimes when I alternately use two keys on my SK61 keyboard with Gateron red switches this happen:

Screenshot 1

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2

[image: Screenshot 2]

I play perfectly, but the keyboard thinks that I hold down one key and either do not press the second one, or press it very briefly with a delay.

Anyone met this problem? How to fix that? I was trying to reset it and it only fixed my fast RGB lightings. Also I was trying to clean my keyboard, but it doesn't give me any result

Comment: how is the keyboard connected?

Comment: How old is it? Has it suffered damage from liquids, mechanical causes (object(s) dropping on it, the keyboard itself dropping off of the desk, button mashing etc) or anything else? Is this keyboard currently also suffering from any other issues?

Comment: The kb connected by type c. I bought it in start of june and it cames like in 29 june. I find this issue in the first day. No more issues. This kb is working okey, but in 200 clicks do this thing randomly on every buttons which i choose to play

Comment: Maybe there's a workaround or a fix, but if none bubbles up here, I would consider replacing it under warranty.

Comment: Yeah.. thank you